# Invoking WebDriver for Tor from Selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tor

I need a Webdriver instance of Tor to be able to launch google.com in tor from selenium, java code in Windows and be able to search for a Target String

My code is below

```
String torPath = "..Installations\\Tor\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe";
String profilePath = "..Installations\\Tor\\TorBrowser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default";
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(profilePath));
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

This results in a blank Tor Browser page opening. It does not load google.com as desired. I know that the profile is valid/compatible because I can successfully start the browser and profile with:

```
binary.startProfile(profile, profilePath, ""));
```

I have looked at similar questions but did not get satisfactory answer.

Can it be done ? If yes , how ? 
I am looking for Java code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver;
    File torProfileDir = new File("C:\\tor\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default");
    FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File( "C:\\tor\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe"));//C:\tor\Tor Browser\Browser
    FirefoxProfile torProfile = new FirefoxProfile(torProfileDir);
    torProfile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
    binary.startProfile(torProfile, torProfileDir);

    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
```

use this code